# css configuration for map template

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3

Hi I'm using a bootstrap template to display some map tools but I been having problems with css of the div containing the map-canvas when I collapse the side panel the map moves to the proper place but live blank space on the opposite side and also there is a big issue with the height of the map.

I'm looking to place the map to full extend when sidepanel is collapsed or extended tried everything without success, I will appreciate any help from the stackoverflow community.

Thanks in advance.

here is a link to my page https://secure.cevamhn.net/AirAid/maptoolsair.php

css code here:

```
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Simple Sidebar HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0; /* disini agar ketika di kecilkan tidak hilang semua default 0*/
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -150px;
}

/*------------------------------------------------  MAP FEATURES BEGIN ----------------------------------*/

#map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#drawPanel {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#color-palette {
    clear: both;
}

.color-button {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 0;
    margin: 2px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#delete-button {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 22px;
}

#wrapper.toggled  #map-canvas #drawPanel #color-palette.color-button #delete-button {
    position: absolute;
}

#botLeft{
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 0px solid;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#botRight{
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 0px solid;
    background-color: transparent;
}

input {
    color: White;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 0px solid;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: left;
}

#opacity {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: white;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

/*------------------------------------------------ END MAP FEATURES ----------------------------------*/

.fixed-brand{
    width: auto;
}
/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    border-left: red 2px solid;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}
.no-margin{
    margin:0;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }
    .fixed-brand{
    width: 250px;
}
    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }
    #wrapper.toggled-2 #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 50px;
    }
    #wrapper.toggled-2 #sidebar-wrapper:hover {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper  {
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    #map-canvas {
    padding: 442px; /* ------------------------------- If left at 0 Map is not Display ---------------------- */
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper  {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
        padding-left: 200px;
    }

     #wrapper.toggled #map-canvas #map-canvas  {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled-2 #page-content-wrapper  {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-left: -220px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled-2 #map-canvas  #map-canvas #drawPanel #color-palette.color-button #delete-button {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry correct link to webpage here: https://secure.cevamhn.net/AirAid/maptoolsair.php

Comment: Edit your question to correct the link.

Comment: Sorry I fix it thanks for the notation

Answer (score 0):

When ever the size of the div containing your map changes, you need to trigger the 'resize' event on your Map object.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Also, by changing:

```
#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

to:

```
#page-content-wrapper {
    min-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

the element stays the width of the space.

Comment: map-canvas div is set  to use 100% of page-content-wraper div that holds it, there is no function resizing the map, is the template's css that manage the divs margins, paddings and resize behaviors, I don't know if  triggering a map resize event will work because the resize behaivior is not created by a function on the map. I may be wrong cuz I'm not familiarized with google maps scripts so if that the reason can you please elaborate a little more on how to implement that trigger event thanks.

Comment: I made the changes on page-content-wrapper anf fix the width issue on the map canvas but the map image still short can u help on the resize trigger event i place ir at the end of cript but nothing happend.

Comment: you need to call `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` or for your page I think `google.maps.event.trigger(mapp, 'resize');` every time the side menu is collapsed/expanded. Try adding that line to the function you use to handle clicking the menu size button.

Comment: this is the functions for the sidepanel: https://secure.cevamhn.net/AirAid/js/sidebar_menu.js

Comment: Great. I don't know your project so I can not write edit that code for you with confidence I am not breaking something else. But now that you have the css fixed, adding `google.maps.event.trigger(myMap, 'resize');` after the element changes size will fix your issue.